# is hapi's server.inject production safe?

Tags: hapi.js

I have encountered server.inject in test examples, but not in production code example.

I have a route that needs to execute something that is handled by another route, so I need to make an internal call.

```
handler: (req, res) => {

const OPTIONS = {
method: 'POST',
path: '/path'
payload: {PAYLOAD_HERE}
}

server.inject(OPTIONS, (err, response) => {
    res(response)
});

}
```

is this okay?

Comment: I have used it however I would ask a question on the https://github.com/hapijs/discuss forum to get a better answer

Comment: Although, `inject` does not return an err and response object. It only returns a response object. Any best practices how to check the response's statusCode and how to use `inject` inside a Promise chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I've done exactly that in a large scale production system.

Comment: random follow up question: are there alternative to server.inject?

Comment: I don't know, I never looked for anything else.  You can always use Request (or a promise wrapped version of it like Yarp) to make an http request out to localhost.  This won't be as fast as `server.inject` which bypasses the http layer.

Comment: Can't you make service method and call that method or series of method from handler or pre block?

Comment: How are you mocking the server.inject in your route for testing then? Any experiences around that are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The route you are calling with server.inject should have its own unit tests.  If that route is making some other http calls you can mock them, but you shouldn't have to mock the server.inject calls.  Remember that server.inject is not making any http calls - it's just hapi calling that route handler function.